# os.path.isfile does not work as expected

Tags: python

I am trying to scan my harddrive for jpg and mp3 files.

I have written the following script which works if I pass it a directory with file in the root but does not return anything if I pass it the root directory.

I am new to Python so would love some help.

```
def findfiles(dirname,fileFilter):

    filesBySize = {}

    def filterfiles(f):
        ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1][1:]
        if ext in fileFilter:
            return True
        else:
            False

    for (path, dirs, fnames) in os.walk(dirname):
        if len(fileFilter)>0:
            fnames = filter(filterfiles,fnames)

        d = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(dirname)      
        for f in fnames:
            if not os.path.isfile(f) :
                continue

            size = os.stat(f)[stat.ST_SIZE]
            if size < 100:
                continue
            if filesBySize.has_key(size):
                a = filesBySize[size]
            else:
                a = []
                filesBySize[size] = a
            a.append(os.path.join(dirname, f))
          #  print 'File Added: %s' %os.path.join(dirname,f)
            _filecount = _filecount + 1
        os.chdir(d)

    return filesBySize
```

Comment: Are you trying to recursively search through directories?

Comment: There's a lot of code in this function. What makes you so sure it is the call to `os.path.isfile(f)` that is going awry? Also your function `filterfiles()` should probably `return ext in fileFilter`, since you have a typo there.

Comment: Yes I am.  I guessing this is the issue as when I step through it the built in function returns false when f is a real file.  I could be way off.  Not sure where you see the typo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah yes.

You're calling `os.path.isfile(f)` where `f` is the filename within the `path`. You'll need to provide an *absolute* path. If, indeed, this call is necessary (it should always return `True`).

Try changing your for-loop to:

```
    qualified_filenames = (os.path.join(path, filename) for filename in fnames)
    for f in qualified_filenames:
```

And you should be set!

Also, the calls to `os.chdir()` are not needed.

And, as I suggested in the comments, `filterfiles` should look more like this:

```
def filterfiles(f):
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1][1:]
    return ext in fileFilter
```

(You missed a `return`).

Answer (score 3):

`filesBySize` is rather unusual grouping. You could move it outside `findfiles()` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import stat
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def findfiles(rootdir, extensions=None, minsize=100):
    """Find files with given `extensions` and larger than `minsize`.

    If `extensions` is None then don't filter on extensions.
    Yield size, filepath pairs.
    """
    extensions = tuple(extensions) if extensions is not None else extensions
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        if extensions is not None: # get files with given extensions
            files = (f for f in files if f.endswith(extensions))
        for f in files:
            f = os.path.join(path, f) 
            try:
                st = os.stat(f)
            except os.error:
                continue # skip
            if stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode): # isfile
               if st.st_size > minsize:
                  yield st.st_size, f

rootdir = sys.argv[1] # get it from command-line
files_by_size = defaultdict(list)
for size, f in findfiles(rootdir, ['.mp3', '.jpg']):
    files_by_size[size // (1<<20)].append((size, f)) # group in 1M buckets

import pprint
pprint.pprint(dict(files_by_size)) # pretty print
```

There is no need to use `os.chdir()`, it is sufficient to call `os.path.join(path, f)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to your question, but here are some general modern Python tips since you are new to Python:

```
os.stat(f)[stat.ST_SIZE]
```

can be written as

```
os.stat(f).st_size
```

and

```
if filesBySize.has_key(size):
    a = filesBySize[size]
else:
    a = []
    filesBySize[size] = a
```

is better written as:

```
a = filesBySize.setdefault(size, [])
```

Comment: or even, [`filesBySize = defaultdict(list); ... filesBySize[size].append(f)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8959455/4279) without `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the constant `os.chdir()` calls here are complicating your program (and might even screw up how `os.walk()` works).

I've copied the better-looking example of how to work with the pathnames without the directory changes from [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
# Delete everything reachable from the directory named in "top",
# assuming there are no symbolic links.
# CAUTION:  This is dangerous!  For example, if top == '/', it
# could delete all your disk files.
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
```

You use `os.path.join(root, name)` once you've selected a `name` from `files`.