# os.path.isfile isn't working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to check if a file exists in Python using `os.path.isfile()`, but it is returning false although the file does exist. For example, when I type `/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg` This is the output

```
Enter the directory to the ISO file (or just drag the file here): /Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg 
/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg 
<type 'str'>
False
```

And the file DOES in fact exist.

[image: file]

Why is this happening?

```
filename = raw_input("Enter the directory to the ISO file (or just drag the file here): ")
print(filename)
print(type(filename))
print(os.path.isfile(filename))
```

Comment: "but it is returning true although the file does exist." uh, did you expect `os.path.isfile` to return `False` even though the file *does exist*?

Comment: you entered a directory name or a file name?

Comment: @Shiping: `os.path.isfile` is correct for checking for a normal file. Of course, if they want either file or directory, `exists` is a good initial test. That said, we have no idea what the user is entering, or what the file system looks like, so this is pretty hard to answer (it's likely an error in the input or file system layout).

Comment: I don't understand your question. `os.path.isfile` returns `True` when the target exists. That's exactly the expected behavior... (at least on linux)

Comment: Sorry guys, typo. I edited the question.

Comment: Since you are not showing us what you typed, the full path of said file, and what the print statements generate (on your machine), we cannot help you.

Comment: how about os.path.isfile()? is it a typo too?

Comment: Have you looked at this very similar question for inspiration?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959187/os-path-isfile-does-not-work-as-expected?rq=1

Comment: @Shiping he edited the question two minutes ago

Comment: I added in more detail @Shiping

Comment: The claimed output couldn't possibly be what the given code actually produced. What is `/dev/disk0s2` coming from, and where did the filename go?

Comment: your output doesn't match the code though.  there's no file name in your output.

Comment: You are using the wrong path.  It should be something along the line of `users/yourname/Desktop/disk0s2` (the name of your file is disk0s2?)

Comment: Now you are using `os.path.exists`, but your question is for `isfile`!

Comment: Ok, I edited my question and it should be good. Sorry guys, I'm really tired and stressed.

Comment: You need to re-verify the output without the typos.

Comment: i'm afraid the file doesn't exist or you mistyped the name.  could you run the command "ls -l /Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [os.path.isfile does not work as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959187/os-path-isfile-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, as posted, works:

File exists

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/surest/github/tests/test.py
Enter the directory to the ISO file (or just drag the file here): /home/surest/Desktop/duties.odt
/home/surest/Desktop/duties.odt
<type 'str'>
True


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Typo in filename/path

```
 /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/surest/github/tests/test.py
Enter the directory to the ISO file (or just drag the file here): /home/surest/Desktop/meesa-typoed.odt
/home/surest/Desktop/meesa-typoed.odt
<type 'str'>
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7, Python 2.7

If you're working with non ASCII letters, then you should decode your input properly. Maybe there are non ASCII letters in your file path that we cannot see. Try this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, locale

filename = raw_input("Enter filepath: ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))
print(filename)
print(type(filename))
print(os.path.exists(filename))
```

It works for path with Cyrillic letters:

```
C:\Projects>c:\Python27\python.exe filepath.py
Enter filepath: c:\Projects\темп\jordanbaron\Рабочий стол\hero-bg.jpg
c:\Projects\темп\jordanbaron\Рабочий стол\hero-bg.jpg
<type 'unicode'>
True
```

Comment: OP is on Mac system.

Comment: The reason you are having to do that is because `temp` is a relative path.  if  a '\' prefixes the path, it must go all the way to the drive path `C`

Comment: @Surest Texas -- Yes, I know. But absolute path also doesn't work for me on Python 2.7.

Comment: Been A couple years since I pythoned in windows, but I think you have to do something like `c\windows\temp\jordan...` or mabe just `c:\windows\temp...`

Comment: You are basically just using a relative path because you don't know the correct absolute path (which is __not__ `/temp/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg`).

Comment: @Surest Texas -- Now I see. It doesn't work for me, because I have Cyrillic letters in my absolute path :-) If move python script in another non-cyrillic path, it works.

Comment: I think it is a little deeper than that..  I don't see any cyrillic letters in your path (from the answer where you attempt absolute path) let me ask you; where is this "temp" directory you are referencing?  is there really a directory/filepath of `C:/temp/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg` on your machine??  isfile has to know every directory all the way up the root of the file system; otherwise only the relative paths work.

Comment: @Surest Texas -- interesting behavior! I took the absolute path 'C:/temp/jordanbaron/Desktop/hero-bg.jpg' and check the file. It worked. Then I changed 1 letter to Cyrillic and check for file path. It stopped to work.

Comment: That is probably just a windows issue with their file system string encodings

Comment: Using non Latin-1 encodings (not actually ASCII) for your file system will cause more problems than just with python.  Ultimately, the OP simply had a typo, which caused incorrect/unexpected output.

Comment: One issue with your edited answer; you say you changed the `e` to a cyrillic `e*`, but your output is still searching for the non-cyrillic e... (and it won't find it because you changed the path; not because it is a non ASCII letter).

Comment: @Surest Texas -- I've rewritten my suggestion to be more explicit and helpful. Now it should work for non Latin-1 encoding.

Comment: Wherever possible, try to avoid using legacy codepages. For console input, use `win_unicode_console` -- or upgrade to Python 3.6, which uses Unicode for the Windows console.