# Work with 2 version of python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, environment-variables

I want to make 2 version (python v3 and python v2) working. I have installed both the versions at different directories. I have also placed their location at the Environment Variables/Path. But, only one version i.e python3 works from command prompt. Yes, for removing the conflict of same filename, I have renamed the python.exe of python v3 to python3.exe

Why is python2 not working??

Using:

```
python
```

throws error: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Directories:

```
Python3: C:\Python36
Python2: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4
```

Paths on Environment Variables/Path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\SASHome\x86\Secure\ccme4;C:\Program Files\SASHome\Secure\ccme4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin; C:\Python36;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4
```

Comment: environment variable only has the name of the directory. I have renamed the filename. So, that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: python3 works. I am concerned about python2.

Comment: paths for both are added??

Comment: Yes. I can even run both of them from their respective directories.

Comment: there could be another issue... u should provide the env variable and directory structure in ques ... it may help!!

Comment: you state above that the path contains: `C:\Python36; C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4`.  if so, you are missing the path `C:\Python27` (no other file or subdirectory).

Comment: why would python two be inside ArcGIS10.4? Is 'ArcGIS10.4' a directory or a file??

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: python27 was installed on my PC by a third party application ArcGIS. Thus, its not installed on the conventional location, rather:     C:\python27\ArcGIS10.4

Comment: That sounds like a problem in itself.  I would remove it and re-install actual python from python.org.. in the correct directory.  It sounds like the python.exe is not in the ArcGIS10.4 folder to me.. you may wich to browse to that directory from windows explorer and verify python.exe is there

Comment: If I installed it to a different path, I am afraid it will not be accessible from the program itself.

Comment: verify the executable exists at that exact location.

Comment: Yes it does. I can even run it from it's location. The problem is, I have to go it's default directory everytime I try to run it.

Comment: try `python.exe` instead of `python`

Comment: No that doesn't work either.

Comment: If that does not work, there must be a syntax error in the path (are you really providing the whole file for us to see.. seems like more should be there than just `C:\Python36; C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4`.. if the path `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4` exists and has a python.exe inside it, there is just NO way you could get this error...

Comment: However, I can go to the respective directories and type just "python" to run it

Comment: The only other alternative I can see is that windows might be viewing `ArcGIS10.4` as a file because of the period..

Comment: That is why I said the path _must_ be defective somehow... bec ause you can run it from the location.

Comment: You should cut and paste the __whole__ path (not just type part of it) for us to look at.  Not to be pedantic about it, but I see typos all the time that can't be caught because the asker is posting something different than really exists on his machine.. For instance on this recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599036/os-path-isfile-isnt-working-as-expected

Comment: Since you are running from a prompt you may want to see what cmd.exe thinks the Path is: `echo %PATH%`... if the solution below does not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be formatting issues in the last portion of your path.

`;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin; C:\Python36;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4`

There is a space that should not be here:

`; C:\Python36`

If removing the space does not correct the problem, then, after removing the space, I would try these things also:

1) change the order some (do this carefully to avoid introducing new errors):
`;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin;C:\Python36`

2) or possibly, adding semicolon to the end:
`;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin;C:\Python36;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4;`

3) You could prepend the path to the beginning (and not the end):

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\SASHome\x86\Secure\ccme4;C:\Program Files\SASHome\Secure\ccme4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin; C:\Python36
```

4) **LAST RESORT** (I question if this would need to be done or would even work):

Put the actual `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Python.exe` in the path somewhere...

Comment: I prepended python2 and removed the spaces and it worked. I did not add .exe in the end though.  Actually I copied all the path to notepad and replaced all the spaces before and after semicolon with nospaces. Thanks.

Comment: This is how it looks like now: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4;....all the other paths;C:\Python36;

Comment: You are welcome... I ran into this stuff a few years ago on my Win machines.  I ended up having to pre-pend, but maybe I had similar error then too..  I was just curious if it will work _wiithout_ the prepend if the space is gone...